# Access Windows Phone 8 Emulator via MTP

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mtp, wpd

Windows phone devices use the MTP protocol to transfer files to and from the device over USB. I'm working on a program that will access files on the device, but I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the Windows Phone 8 emulator using MTP.

I can access a hardware device easily enough, but I'm not too keen on doing testing on my phone itself in case I screw something up. Does anyone know if it's possible to communicate with the emulator using MTP?

Comment: i need to transfer xml/text/html file from wp8 to PC and vice versa,if you can you share any code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: see Windows Phone Power Tools' source code.